# DB2 : ' ' taking as null while insert

Tags: database, insert, db2-luw

I am trying to insert values in table

```
Test(id number,name varchar(20) not null);
insert into Test values(1,' '); //executing correctly
```

but for below statement

```
insert into Test values(1,'');//showing here null value cannot be accepted for not null column.
```

can anyone explain me why ' ' taking as null in DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your DB2 database uses the [Oracle compatibility mode](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html) and has [VARCHAR2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052880.html?lang=en) support enabled. Once the Oracle mode or `VARCHAR2` mode is on for a database, empty strings are treated as NULL values. I recommend checking the database configuration (`get db cfg`) for the `varchar2_compat` setting.

Comment: Thanks henrik,yes my db2_compatibility_vector set to 'ORA'

Comment: Then the behavior is as designed. Please mark my response as answer.